# Meteor blocking clarification

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor, blocking

According to the meteor docs, inserts block:

> On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then insert blocks
>   until the database acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if
>   something went wrong. If you do provide a callback, insert still
>   returns the ID immediately.

So this would be wrong:

```
Meteor.methods({
  post: function (options) {
    return Stories.insert(options)
  }
});
```

I need to do this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  post: function (options) {
    return Stories.insert(options, function(){})
  }
});
```

Can somebody confirm that this is the case? The former will block the ENTIRE SERVER until the db returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it will block, but not the entire server.

> In Meteor, your server code runs in a single thread per request, not in the asynchronous callback style typical of Node. We find the linear execution model a better fit for the typical server code in a Meteor application.

So, if you are worried about that it will block the entire server as it will do in typical Node, don't be.

Comment: So either methods is fine Aaron?

Comment: That depends on your demand. Do you need to wait for safe writing and how would you handle exception? You have known the difference between them, didn't you?

Comment: Nope, I don't. Any further info or clarification would be educational and highly appreciated. Thanks in advance Aaron.

Comment: I think, most of times, the former would be just fine. If you don't want it to throw an exception when something goes wrong, use a callback(err, result) and check whether a error has occurred. If you don't care whether the write success and you need return as soon as possible to save waiting time, use the latter.