# Does Meteor server-side collection insert blocking process?

Tags: asynchronous, collections, meteor, nonblocking

In http://docs.meteor.com/#insert there is a statement:

> On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then **insert blocks** until the database acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if something went wrong.

Is it entire node process going blocked there ? Do we always need to provide a callback ?

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076788/meteor-blocking-clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not blocking the whole process. It just looks synchronous, in reality the Fiber (current execution context, cooperative thread) yields to other events in the event loop. You can safely use it but be careful: something can execute in the period of time after yielding and regaining the control.